# 'Unknown Display' in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, display

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and the first thing I noticed was that in the display settings, my monitor was not recognized. I tried every solution that I found in the forums but nothing actually helped.

Comment: Please add the output of `lshw -C display`...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? Resolution, monitor's name?

You should try adding `xrandr` command output here.

Also, are you using any DVI->VGA connector? I've had problem same problem with one. My solution was changing it to good one (Gigabyte) and it worked just fine!